# Is there a way to include an implicit "yes" in ssh commands?

Tags: python, ssh, emr

I'm using MacOS, and I'm creating a process to open an ssh tunnel to an EMR cluster on creation.  Due to the firewall, this is a connection that needs to be maintained for the duration you wish to look at the Spark web UI, and so I need to figure out how to:

1. Open the ssh tunnel (and implicitly tell it include "yes" when it asks if I want to connect to this new server)
2. Then open a web-browser to the correct port.

Here is my command I'm currently using:

```
               ssh = sp.Popen(
                    [
                        'ssh',
                        '-i',
                        KEY_PAIR,
                        '-ND',
                        '8157',
                        'hadoop@{host}'.format(host=master_dns)
                    ],
                    shell=False,
                    stdin=sp.PIPE,
                    stdout=sp.PIPE,
                    stderr=sp.PIPE,
                    universal_newlines=True
                )
                sleep(1)
                out, err = ssh.communicate(input='yes')
                print(out, err)
               print('URL to Yarn Manager: {url}'.format(
                    url='http://{dns}:8088'.format(dns=master_dns)
                ))
                input("Hit any key to terminate the ssh tunnel.")
                ssh.terminate()
```

This doesn't seem to work as it still asks me

```
ECDSA key fingerprint is XXXX.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

after the fact.  What would be a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use yes or expect as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804577/have-bash-script-answer-interactive-prompts

Comment: Thank you!  We can close as duplicate