# How to run system command and get continuous output in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, console, jupyter-notebook, outputstream

If I run a system command in Jupyter Notebook I would expect that log messages of my console application are shown "immediately" in the notebook. However, it seems that they only occur after the complete process has been finished.

I tried

```
!D:/long_running_executable_with_log_messages.exe
```

and

```
import os
os.system('D:/long_running_executable_with_log_messages.exe')
```

=>How can I get the output of the system command continuously?

Related question:

[Running interactive command line code from Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604027/running-interactive-command-line-code-from-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CalledProcessError

with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line, end='') # process line here

if p.returncode != 0:
    raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, p.args)
```

Found at [Constantly print Subprocess output while process is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running)