# passing subprocess run prompt input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

I am passing a user input using python subprocess using input in subprocess.run

```
dargs = ['java','-jar','cli.jar','ion','-cf', config_path, '-r', deldata.get("reg"), '-n', deldata.get("space"), '-e', deldata.get("tion"), '-c', listargs[2], '-f', 'true']
dresp = subprocess.run(dargs, text=True, capture_output=True, input="yes")
```

This returns following error :

```
returned non-zero exit status 1.
When calling: subprocess.run(dargs, text=True, capture_output=True, check=True, input="yes")
```

but the same if I do from terminal it works fine

```
java -jar cli.jar ion -r DUB -n oa -cf /config/path -e test -c ht -f true
```

The above command outputs the following and asks for user input like this in terminal

```
this is force operation.
V Id: sl, Desc: ht
Confirm operation: (yes/no)yes #----->here comes my user input to terminal
Operation done successfully
```

command triggered from terminal first outputs this two lines

```
this is force operation.
V Id: sl, Desc: ht
```

Then waits for sometime and then asks for input
Confirm operation: (yes/no)

Not sure how to make subprocess not pipe and send the `yes` input rather wait for prompt and check for this line `Confirm operation: (yes/no)` and then provide the input as `yes` or `no`

I believe with my current code its performing
`yes | java -jar cli.jar ion -r DUB -n oa -cf /config/path -e test -c ht -f true` kind of operation which is not excepted by cli.

Any help on how to achieve this will be great

Comment: You can try using parts from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48787335/7916438, it shows how to send input to a `subprocess`. I'm not sure about the output part, in a terminal it may not be necessary to redirect it at all and it would just simply appear.

Comment: @tevemadar as far as I am aware providing input="whatever" works right ?
and the reference you are providing that is of subprocess.popen

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a `\r`at the end os the string in the input argument ( `input="yes\r", ...`). Also, this depends on "cli.jar" being in the same folder the Python script is, and calling the Python script from that folder. Adding the full absolute path to "cli.jar" will help.

Funny thing is that without passing "check=True" to subprocess.run, the program should not break: you'd just get the failed run information on your `dresp` program, and you can print that to get whatever information the program you tried to run printed out (due to capture_output=True).

If it does not work, try to break your case in steps, like, try to run `java -version` first, so you can assert the java interpreter is being located and run successfully. Also, if your program is not breaking at the call, just add a  `print(dresp)` there.

Comment: I have kept the cli.jar in same path that works fine in other subprocess commands that I am running where there is no need to pass the input.
I have removed `check=True` java interpreter also works fine as other subprocess commands are running.
rather when I added `yes\r` in input it does take the input now but it looks like the process is completed and then it provides the value to subprocess..atleast it is not exiting with the previous error
but still it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: is it possible to pass input after some delay ?

Comment: I figured out the issue but not sure what is the solution
actually it fails if I pipe the input and send. In my above code subprocess is doing this same as in this terminal I believe
`yes | java -jar cli.jar ion -r DUB -n oa -cf /config/path -e test -c ht -f true`
cli has restrictions in execution like this any workaround in python for this to pass the input?