# How to Securely Add a List of Hosts to known_hosts File

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a file that contains ~1000 hosts, one host per line. For each host, I want to check if an entry for the host already exists in the `known_hosts` file. If one does not, I want to add the host to the `known_hosts` file. Otherwise, I want to update the existing entry. I would like to use the `-H` option to hash all entries in `known_hosts`. I have already run the command `ssh-keygen -H ~/.ssh/known_hosts` to hash the existing entries.

Here is a simple loop that I put together:

```
while read LINE; do
    # Remove entry if it exists
    ssh-keygen -R $LINE
    # Append new hashed key to file
    ssh-keyscan -H $LINE >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
done < $HOST_FILE
```

Is this method secure? If not, what is the recommended way of doing this? The reason I am doing this is to disable typing "yes" 1000 times to allow every new host to be added to `known_hosts` for scripting purposes.

Comment: Take a look at this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804577/have-bash-script-answer-interactive-prompts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804577/have-bash-script-answer-interactive-prompts)

Answer (score 1):

What's interactive here?  You're piping data into your while loop and neither of the commands in the loop involve user interactivity.  I see this as secure.

Note: `ssh-keyscan` drops comments to standard error and you might want to filter them out.  You probably also don't need the errors from `ssh-keygen` when the requested host isn't present:

```
while read LINE; do
    # Remove entry if it exists
    ssh-keygen -R "$LINE" 2>/dev/null
    # Append new hashed key to file
    ssh-keyscan -H "$LINE" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts 2>/dev/null
done < "$HOST_FILE"
```

You may also be interested in [ssh-hosthashes](https://github.com/adamhotep/net-scripts/blob/master/ssh-hosthashes), a script I wrote a while back that looks for duplicate entries in `known_hosts` files.  This finds duplicates by the public keys, so it will cluster entries regardless of whether they are listed by IP, name, or hash.