# EB CLI - how to suppress code commit prompt "Do you wish to continue with CodeCommit?"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

Every time I use a command on the Elastic Beanstalk CLI  like `eb init` or `eb deploy` it prompts me with:

> Do you wish to continue with CodeCommit? (y/N) (default is n):

And I always say 'no'.

**Is there a way to suppress this prompt or provide a default answer?**

I have checked the EB CLI documentation but I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using this command programatically, you can pass a negative response to the `eb init` or `eb deploy` with a [Unix command called `yes`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)) - the name seems to contradict what you're trying to achieve, but it can be used to pass a user-definied string instead of the default affirmative response. Usage:

```
yes n | eb deploy
```

It will behave as if you pressed the 'n' key. Keep in mind that 'n' will be looped (it will be an answer to all the prompts during the command execution).

Another option is using [`printf`](https://linuxconfig.org/bash-printf-syntax-basics-with-examples):

```
printf '\n\n\n\n' | eb deploy
```

This would behave as if you pressed the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key 4 times (4 prompts).

There are some more alternatives and usage examples in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804577/have-bash-script-answer-interactive-prompts).

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about the 'yes' command. But I was hoping for a more robust solution as I use it in scripts as well as  manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to suppress all prompts from [`eb init`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-init.html), pass the `--platform PLATFORM_NAME` argument. A complete command might look like:

```
eb init APPLICATION_NAME \
    --region REGION_NAME \
    --platform PLATFORM_NAME
```