# Automatically run the command alternatives --config java to choose the option provided with update-alternatives --install

Tags: java, shell, centos

I have a simple requirement to be able to automate installing some other JDK on CentOS machine that already has its own JDK installed. As such here are the steps I execute on the CentOS node:

```
tar -zxvf jdk-8u221-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/jdk1.8.0_221/bin/java 2
alternatives --config java // and select 2 to proceed
```

Now under the final step I get the prompt and then have to manually enter 2. So all of that works fine.
However, is there a way to skip the prompt and get that installed directly. The reason is because I am looking to automate this using a shell script.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have bash script answer interactive prompts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804577/have-bash-script-answer-interactive-prompts)

Comment: Thanks Mark. So i believe in my case it would be just 
2 | alternatives --config java
If so i will try that out because for my use case its always going to be entering 2 at the prompt after alternatives --config java

Comment: I was able to solve this using simply 
alternatives --config java <<< '2'
That did the trick for me

Comment: Or we could also simply do
echo -e "2" | alternatives --config java