# How to automate password prompt coming from Shell script B ,using Shell script A?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, bash, shell, automation

Im running a Shell script A which executes another Shell script B which asks for password from user. How to automate password input using Shell script A?

Tried below

```bash
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l $USER $host "sudo bash -s" < $MYLOC/shellscriptB.sh<<EOD
expect "Enter password"
send "welcome1@"
EOD
```

but getting error

```
line 77: /usr/bin/expect: No such file or directory`.
```

Unable to install `except` using `sudo yum install except`, as getting  error

```
No package available
```

Comment: Does [passing arguments to an interactive program non-interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392525/) or [have bash script answer interactive prompts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804577) answer your question?

Comment: Why is this tagged Python?

Comment: Aside from the fact that the expect script itself is buggy, you of course need to install `expect` if you don't have it yet. However it is surprising that your Linux distro does not already have it. My suggestion is that you first take care about the installation problem. This needs to be posted at i.e. [su], because it is not a programming problem. Once you have it, come back here and we can discuss your Tcl script.